# How to Disable Kite Copilot Feature?

Tags: python, spyder, kite

I recently installed Kite for Spyder 4. I think I wanted to give it a try for several weeks and see how it performs.

One feature called Kite-copilot annoys me, it pops up whenever I opened spyder. I don't really use that feature much since it is in the new window (it would cover my workspace if it is always on top, and it would be covered by spyder if it didn't).

So is there a way to disable this particular feature? I know I can just close it right away whenever it pops out, but it is kinda annoying that I always need to close it first whenever I opened spyder.

Comment: Does it still annoy you?

Comment: Still annoys me. Furthermore, I realize that kite is using so much resources. So I finally decided to uninstall it though.

Comment: No answer yet. I came here looking for a way to disable the auto-launch  with Spyder.  No readily available answers on the net for that.

Comment: I had the problem of having kite using too many resources and wanted to disable it without uninstalling. What I did was the following: Tools -> Preferences -> Completion and linting. In the `Advanced` tab, under the `Providers` section, uncheck `Enable Kite`. Now Spyder doesn't even say `Kite: not running`. You can try and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately in Spyder 5.05 there is no ```Providers``` section under ```Tools->Preferences-> Completion and linting->Advanced```.

Answer (score 0):

On MacBook switch off kite for current session: at the top right of the screen (top menu bar where your wifi shows etc) locate the kite icon. Right click on it and select 'quit kite'. You will see in Spyder at the bottom (just below Console) the Kite status should switch to 'Kite: not running'.